# What does "broadcast level" mean?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Niobe warns Zion people about sentinels entering their territory:

> Ghost: And if Niobe's right, in 72 hours there's gonna be a quarter of
> a million more.
>
> Ballard: What are we gonna do about it?
>
> Niobe: We're gonna do what Commander Lock ordered us to do. We'll
> evacuate  **broadcast level** and return to Zion.

What does "broadcast level" mean?

Comment: Chances are it just means they're going to evacuate everyone by using a broadcast message/broadcasting an evacuation message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kind of always assumed that broadcast level was a certain depth or location where the pirate signal they used to infiltrate the Matrix would reach to the network, and below this level or location, I.e. closer to Zion, it wouldn't be possible to broadcast the signal, so not possible to enter the Matrix.